# Change the projection of the xarray dataset

Tags: python, raster, netcdf, python-xarray, projection

I have two nc. files Sentinel2 and Landsat8. Sentinel2 is in epsg:32633 and Landsat8 is in epsg:4326. I want to reproject the Sentinel2 to epsg:4326 (same as the Landsat8).
[image]

For now, I used the rio.reproject_match and rio.reproject. But this completely changed the Sentinel 2 values.

```
S2_4326 = S2.rio.reproject_match(LS8)
```

[image]

I tried also rio.reproject but it also changed the values, and I want to change only the projection:

```
S2_4326=S2.rio.reproject('epsg:4326', inplace = True)
```

[image]

[You can download the data here as Lansat8.nc and Sentinel2.nc](https://github.com/MartinKAJO/Euro-Cordex.git)

Do you have any ideas on reprojecting the Sentinel2 to WGS84 and not changing the original values but only the coordinates?

Comment: It doesn't look the values have changed. The values outside the box are 1e38 or something similar. But they should me missing values. Just fix them to missing values, and your ranges will probably be OK